# NodeJS Datagram - Receive IPv6 multicast

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, ipv6, datagram

I'm trying to receive multicast datagrams over IPv6 in node.js. I had no problems doing  it exactly same way over IPv4 (udp4), but trying to do the same for udp6 gives me EINVAL Errors on `socket.addMembership` call. Here is my code:

```
var dgram = require('dgram');
var server = dgram.createSocket('udp6');

var PORT = 12345;
var MULTICAST_ADDRESS = 'ff7e:230::1234';

server.on('message', function (message, remote) {
    console.log('Message from: ' + remote.address + ':' + remote.port +' - ' + message);
});

server.on('listening', function () {
  var address = server.address();
  console.log('UDP listening on ' + address.address + ":" + address.port);
  server.addMembership(MULTICAST_ADDRESS);
});

server.bind(PORT);
```

This causes:

```
    Error: addMembership EINVAL
            at new errnoException (dgram.js:454:11)
            at Socket.addMembership (dgram.js:396:11)
            at Socket.<anonymous> (/media/sf_projects/ipv6_multicast/server.js:57:10)
            at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)
            at startListening (dgram.js:141:10)
            at dgram.js:213:7
            at dns.js:72:18
            at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
            at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:499:11)
            at startup (node.js:119:16)
```

When I comment out `server.addMembership(MULTICAST_ADDRESS);` the socket binds with success, but no datagrams are received.

I tried to call `addMembership` with my IPv6 as second argument, but this also gives EINVAL.

```
server.addMembership(MULTICAST_ADDRESS,  'fe80::a00:27ff:fed1:cac9');
```

I also tried to bind the socket to specific interface:

```
server.bind(PORT, 'fe80::a00:27ff:fed1:cac9');
```

a this also gives me EINVAL on bind method.

Here is output of my ifconfig:

```
    eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:d1:ca:c9  
                      inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
                      inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fed1:cac9/64 Scope:Link
                      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
                      RX packets:8996 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
                      TX packets:6081 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
                      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
                      RX bytes:8389966 (8.3 MB)  TX bytes:510795 (510.7 KB)

    lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
                      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
                      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
                      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
                      RX packets:356 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
                      TX packets:356 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
                      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
                      RX bytes:33534 (33.5 KB)  TX bytes:33534 (33.5 KB)
```

Comment: I am a bit confused about your multicast address. `ff7e:` means that it is a multicast address with global scope and with embedded rendez-vous point address, but the rest of the address does not match the pattern for embedded rendez-vous point addresses as defined in RFC 3956. Could you tell how that address was defined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to bind to a link-local (`fe80:`) address you'll have to specify *which* link you want. Unfortunately I haven't found a way to do that for NodeJS. If you bind to a global IPv6 address it will work.

For the multicast support you seem to be out of luck... NodeJS only seems to support IPv4 multicast. A call to `addMembership` is implemented as a call to `uv_udp_set_membership`, which contains IPv4-only code. It parses the IP address with `inet_addr`, it calls `setsockopt` with the `IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP` options while IPv6 needs `IPV6_ADD_MEMBERSHIP` etc.

NodeJS seems to be a bit behind on their IPv6 implementation :(

If you are interested you can see the source code here: https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/deps/uv/src/unix/udp.c

Comment: Thanks. I think that I'll create an issiue for this on node.js issue tracker. I was experimenting with different addresses.

Comment: Good to see that people are working on IPv6 support! Too bad that NodeJS isn't as far as you :)

Comment: I created issue for this one: [Need support for IPv6 Multicast in dgram](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/6893)

Comment: @MichaelHampton I tried `server.bind(PORT, 'fe80::...%en0');` on my Mac OS box and it didn't work, while binding to a global unicast address with `server.bind(PORT, '2a00:8640:....');` did work. I haven't looked at the internals to see if this bug is Mac OS specific though...